# Redirect stdin for multiple shell functions

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

How to I force this script to do what I intended?

```
#!/bin/bash

function One()
{
  IFS='' read -r -n1 CHAR
  echo "One: '$CHAR'"
  Two
}

function Two()
{
  IFS='' read -r n1 CHAR
  echo "Two: '$CHAR'"
}

One < MyFile.txt
```

What's *supposed* to happen is that `One()` reads the first character from `MyFile.txt`, and then `Two()` reads the second character. However, `Two()` always reads an empty character, and I have absolutely no why *why*... Any hints?

```
# bash -x Test.sh
+ One
+ IFS=
+ read -r -n1 CHAR
+ echo 'ONE: '\''S'\'''
One: 'S'
+ Two
+ IFS=
+ read -r n1 CHAR
Two: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

GAH! I just figured it out... It *looks like* the redirection gets reset when you invoke another function. But that's not it. The *real* problem is much more dumb:

```
IFS='' read -r n1 CHAR
```

There's a dash missing!

```
IFS='' read -r -n1 CHAR
```

[facepalm]